# Yii: Is is possible to link a specified CJuiTabs from external page?

Tags: yii

I've a page with a CjuiTab, with seven tabs.

I need a link into from external page or from the same page, to REFRESH the page directly a the specified tab.

I need to use ChtmlLink, but how to append '#' to end of url ?

```
CHtml::link (Yii::t('general','Annulla'),
             array("company/update", 
            'id'=> $companyId)
```

where / how to append '#contactTab' !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass a `'#'=>'value'`. The value of the url parameter for `CHtml::link` is ultimately passed to `CController::createUrl`, and the [doc states](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail):

> additional GET parameters (name=>value). Both the name and value will be URL-encoded. If the name is '#', the corresponding value will be treated as an anchor and will be appended at the end of the URL.

So try with:

```
CHtml::link (Yii::t('general','Annulla'),
    array(
        "company/update", 
        'id'=> $companyId,
        '#'=>'contactTab'
    )
);
```

---

Update: For same page links you'll need to use some javascript to reload the page *after* the browser url is set:

```
CHtml::link (Yii::t('general','Annulla'),
    array(
        "company/update", 
        'id'=> $companyId,
        '#'=>'contactTab'
    ),
    array('onclick'=>'setTimeout("location.reload(true);",100);')
);
```

(Not sure if this is the best way to reload though)

Comment: That's working ! Only one problem: in FF the page will not be realoaded if link is internal at the page ..

Comment: meaning the link and the target tab are in the same page? didn't you ask for external?

Comment: hmm, for that you'll just have to reload page with javascript

Comment: ... from internal, i need first to append '#contactTab' is there isn't yet and then to reload ... I cannot understand how to make this possible using button, link, linkbutton, or similar ...

Comment: Wow ! I haven't thinked about to add a setTimeout ... because some browser execute the onclick before ajax and other execute first the ajax .... in this way all is working ... great !